Query getting cancelled by WLM in PROD but works fine in DEV with same WLM in Redshift
I have a query with join 6 tables. The query gets cancelled in PROD by the WLM rule. But the same query provides data in DEV. The WLM rules and data are same throughout the environment.
I tried vacuum and analyse. I truncated the table and loaded the data. Still the query is cancelled by the WLM rule in PROD.
Redshift Database

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

What WLM rule is cancelling the query?  There are a number of conditions that can do this.  Also is the cluster size and data stored the same in prod and dev?  Is this a timeout due to more data in prod?
